# Spring Boot Devtools: exclude multiple modules from restart classloader

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

From documentation **[Customizing the Restart Classloader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload)**, you can add devtools dependency and exclude unneeded jars from restart classloader with `META-INF/spring-devtools.properties`.

### Problem

I came to multimodule maven project. About 50 modules. Don't ask me why, I don't know too. As I understand to exclude `module49.jar` from restart classloader I have to create `module49/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-devtools.properties` file. To exclude 47 modules' jars I have to create 47 `spring-devtools.properties` files, right?

### Question

I know, 50 maven modules is totally wrong approach, but *Is there any way to create one `spring-devtools.properties` file?*

### P.S.

For my case it would be better to exclude everything from restart classloader and create a small whitelist of modules that support hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

You can put spring-devtools.properties file to the main module of your application (from where SpringBootApplication starts) and write all modules in this one file. For example:

```
restart.exclude.first=/modules/first/
restart.exclude.second=/modules/second/
```

etc...

In my case, modules contained inside larger groups. If the same for you, it is possible just place groups there:

```
restart.exclude.group1=/modules/group1/
...
```

Comment: @user2532617 the question is that I cannot configure path from my launcher module to my core module. Both modules `launcher` and `core` modules lays on the same level. When I do `jar -tf launcher.jar | grep core-1.0.jar` I get `BOOT-INF/lib/core-1.0.jar`. But adding `BOOT-INF/lib/core-1.0.jar` to `spring-devtools.properties` file does not  exclude `core-1.0.jar` from restart classloader